# Definir o nome de uma propriedade dinamicamente em VB.NET

Tags: json, vb.net, propriedade

Tenho uma classe com uma propriedade pública nela. Como segue no exemplo:

```
Public Property exemplo As List(Of Uso)
        Get
            Return x_exemplo 
        End Get
        Set
            x_exemplo = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private x_exemplo As List(Of Uso)
```

Consigo usá-la tranquilamente. Porém, o que preciso é definir o nome dela dinamicamente. Ou seja, o nome "exemplo" não pode ser fixo. As vezes será exemplo2, outras "teste", etc. Isso é possível? Chamar alguma função ou método que defina o nome da propriedade?

No meu arquivo principal, a classe é chamada durante a leitura de um arquivo JSON:

```
For Each valor In classe-principal.propriedade-da-classe-principal.propriedade-de-outra-classe.exemplo
...
Next
```

Ou seja, "propriedade-da-classe-principal", "propriedade-de-outra-classe" são nomes das chaves do arquivo JSON. "exemplo" também é, porém é um nome dinâmico, que dependendo do arquivo, muda de nome. Já consegui identificar o nome da chave que é dinâmica, só preciso usar esse nome como 'nome da propriedade', para que eu consiga entrar nela e pegar os valores seguintes do json.

Answer (score 1):

Eu não sei qual biblioteca você está utilizando pra deserializar o JSON, mas ela provavelmente oferece uma forma de deserializar para um `Dictionary`. Neste caso você precisa deserializar para um `Dictionary(Of String, Object)`, daí você acessa a propriedade dinamicamente (pois a chave do dicionário é uma `String`) e faz um cast de `Object` pro tipo que você quiser.

Answer (score -1):

Seria algo como o método CallByName do Vb?

Você utiliza a chamada do método basicamente por uma String
Por Exemplo:

```
Sub TestCallByName1()
    'Definir a propriedade Text no TextBox1.
    CallByName(TextBox1, "Text", CallType.Set, "New Text")

    'Obter o valor da propriedade Text no TextBox1.
    MsgBox(CallByName(TextBox1, "Text", CallType.Get))

    'Chamando um método.
    CallByName(TextBox1, "Hide", CallType.Method)
End Sub
```

Mais informações podem ser obtidas na página oficial da [documentação
CallByName da Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.callbyname?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Olá @eleison, esse link pode ser uma boa sugestão, mas sua resposta não terá validade se um dia o link deixar de funcionar. Além disso, é importante para a comunidade ter conteúdo aqui no site mesmo. Seria melhor incluir mais detalhes na sua resposta. Um resumo do conteúdo do link já ajudaria bastante! Saiba mais sobre o assunto neste item do nosso FAQ da Comunidade: [Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42/74)

Comment: Muito obrigado @LucasDuete , peços desculpas, pois sou novo nas interações. Efetuei a edição conforme você mencionou.